# Is it POSSIBLE for Google App Engine standard app to access local computer's files?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a maven java project that uses Google App Engine and Google Cloud Storage. I'm trying to write an API that can upload files from a local computer to Google Cloud Storage.
When I execute the app locally(localhost:8080), it uploads files to GCS with no errors. However, I keep get **filenotfoundexception** and **nosuchfileexception** error whenever I deploy the app on GAE.

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days but I haven't got a clue to fix it.

```
    {
     "bucketName": "{my-bucket-name}",
     "uploadFileName": "{my-object-name}",
     "localFileLocation": "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt"
    }
```

Above is a json format that I use to call the API that uploads file to GCS. I guess that there is a problem with the `localFileLocation` variable. I thought it shouldn't be an absolute path, so I've tried using a relative path but it still doesn't work.

So, is there any way that I can access local machine files through Google App Engine?
Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using signed url for my Goolge Cloud Storage bucket. I was on this problem for a week and figured that there is no proper way to get to your own file path(like C:/users/) when you are running your project on GAE.

Guess this [google doc(uploading objects to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) is only helpful when your project is running locally. So the solution to my problem was to generate a signed URL for my bucket and access to the bucket by it. Here is the link that was helpful: [how to create signed url for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#code-samples)

Thank you to all who answered this question anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reference files on your local machine when running code in GAE (or at least, extremely difficult to set up).  You will need to come up with a way to push those local files somewhere into Google Cloud (or any cloud service really) so they can be accessed from GAE via whatever API is provided by the product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to be clear, does it mean that I cannot upload files to Google Cloud Storage while I’m running code in GAE?(like in the question, it worked when I launched it locally) Because I’m trying to come up with an website that users can upload their pictures/videos. I tried to do it by uploading files to GCS while running code in GAE, but it seems like I need different methods.

Comment: You can definitely work with files in Cloud Storage from GAE.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your GCS bucket in the console, then drag and drop whatever local files you want to upload to the GCS cloud.  Don't bother trying to do that programmatically.

If you want a web site where users can upload their own local files to your GCS storage, you can create a web `<form>`. A drag-and-drop method is a bit advanced, but there is plenty of code online for you to use. Otherwise, a simple `<input type="file">` field in your form will work.  You've seen them before:

[image]

Then, you process the file in App Engine and upload it programmatically to your GCS bucket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with kind examples! I’d definitely try that. But I have one more question. Is there any way that I can upload files to the bucket only using APIs(without the <form> and <input> tags you suggested)? Because I’m trying to use Postman app and see responses with the API and build UI later. I appreciate your answer anyways. It helped a lot

Comment: There are only a few ways for your app to receive files:  From a fetch, where it is given a URL, then goes and fetches the file (example: fetching from a GCS bucket).  From a POST request, where someone POSTs the file to your app's url handler (this is what a web form does, but another app could also POST to your url).  From a local file (in dev only. The production server cannot read your local files).